# Python-BS4 text inside <span> that has no class

Tags: web-scraping

I have those 2 span with text inside them.They have no class or id and i want to scrape that text with bs4 but i don't know how.Using the small tag don't help me becouse the html is full of those.
Can someone help me with an exemple?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLD3k.jpg)

```
<td valign="bottom" class="bottom-cell">
<div class="space rel">
    <p class="lheight16">
         <small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
               <span><i data-icon="location-filled"></i>Iasi</span>
         </small>
         <small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
               <span><i data-icon="clock"></i>Ieri 16:13</span>
          </small>
     </p>
```

Comment: Don't post images of code. Add them as text to your question, along with your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

try this, The `:nth-of-type(1)` selector matches every span element that is the 1th child, of a particular type, of its parent.

```
for i in data.select('.lheight16 small span:nth-of-type(1)'):
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to do this, but most will orientate on the `parents` of the `span`s - Cause there is no expected output (recommend you should improve that) in your question, check these two.

Option a:

```
for span in soup.select('td.bottom-cell span'):
    print(span.get_text())
```

Option:b

```
print(soup.select_one('td.bottom-cell').get_text(' - ',strip=True))
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<td valign="bottom" class="bottom-cell">
<div class="space rel">
    <p class="lheight16">
         <small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
               <span><i data-icon="location-filled"></i>Iasi</span>
         </small>
         <small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
               <span><i data-icon="clock"></i>Ieri 16:13</span>
          </small>
     </p>
</div>
</td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

#option a:
for span in soup.select('td.bottom-cell span'):
    print(span.get_text())

#option:b    
print(soup.select_one('td.bottom-cell').get_text(' - ',strip=True))
```

**Output**
a:

```
Iasi
Ieri 16:13
```

b:

```
Iasi - Ieri 16:13
```